# Parse REST XML file

Tags: vb.net, rest, windows

I am working on a .NET 3.5 Windows Forms application that will interact with a REST Web Service which outputs an XML file such as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Response Status="OK">
<Item Name="NumberZones">2</Item>
<Item Name="CurrentZoneID">10001</Item>
<Item Name="CurrentZoneIndex">1</Item>
<Item Name="ZoneName0">Westralia</Item>
<Item Name="ZoneID0">0</Item>
<Item Name="ZoneGUID0">{81C56183-31DA-45C2-90C3-81609F01B38B}</Item>
<Item Name="ZoneName1">Lounge</Item>
<Item Name="ZoneID1">10001</Item>
<Item Name="ZoneGUID1">{eac0109e-0090-a992-7fba-dc67fe29e6e7}</Item>
</Response>
```

What I am needing assistance with, is how do I parse this file so that I am able to get the value of the Item Name (such as ZoneName0), and the attribute value (in this case Westralia).

I have been playing with using xDocument to parse the XML document and have been able to do this, however it is extremely slow which I think is because I am looping through the XML document and attempting to match the item name:

```
Public Function getZoneDetails(ByVal serverName As String, ByVal serverPort As String) As DataTable
        Dim sResult As DataTable
        sResult = New DataTable("ZoneDetails")
        With sResult
            .Columns.Add("column")
            .Columns.Add("data")
            .Columns.Add("zoneID")
            .Columns.Add("result")
        End With
        xmlDocPath = "temp.xml"
        If Not DownloadXml(serverName, serverPort, "Playback/Zones", xmlDocPath) Then
            Dim fDtRow As DataRow = sResult.NewRow()
            fDtRow.Item(0) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(1) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(2) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(3) = "Error downloading XML"
            sResult.Rows.Add(fDtRow)
            Return sResult
        End If
        If Not LoadXml(xmlDocPath) Then
            Dim fDtRow As DataRow = sResult.NewRow()
            fDtRow.Item(0) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(1) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(2) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(3) = "Error loading XML internally"
            sResult.Rows.Add(fDtRow)
            Return sResult
        End If
        Try
            ' Make sure <status> = OK
            Dim status As String = xdoc.Root.Attribute("Status").Value
            If status <> "OK" Then
                Dim fDtRow As DataRow = sResult.NewRow()
                fDtRow.Item(0) = ""
                fDtRow.Item(1) = ""
                fDtRow.Item(2) = ""
                fDtRow.Item(3) = "No route can be mapped out"
                sResult.Rows.Add(fDtRow)
                Return sResult
            End If

            Dim zoneID As String = String.Empty
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each obj In xdoc.Root.Elements("Item").Attributes("Name")
                Dim nRow As DataRow = sResult.NewRow()
                If obj.Value = "ZoneID" + i.ToString Then
                    zoneID = obj.Parent.Value
                    nRow.Item(0) = "ZoneID"
                    nRow.Item(1) = zoneID
                    nRow.Item(2) = zoneID
                    nRow.Item(3) = "OK"
                End If

                If obj.Value = "ZoneName" + i.ToString Then
                    nRow.Item(0) = "ZoneName"
                    nRow.Item(1) = obj.Parent.Value
                    nRow.Item(2) = zoneID
                    nRow.Item(3) = "OK"
                End If

                If obj.Value = "ZoneGUID" + i.ToString Then
                    nRow.Item(0) = "ZoneGUID"
                    nRow.Item(1) = obj.Parent.Value
                    nRow.Item(2) = zoneID
                    nRow.Item(3) = "OK"
                End If
                i = i + 1
                sResult.Rows.Add(nRow)
            Next
            Return sResult
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim fDtRow As DataRow = sResult.NewRow()
            fDtRow.Item(0) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(1) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(2) = ""
            fDtRow.Item(3) = "Error occured"
            sResult.Rows.Add(fDtRow)
            Return sResult
        End Try
    End Function
```

I am wanting to read the XML, assign the attributes and the attribute names into a dataset to be bound to a drop down list.

Can anyone advise if there is a better method doing what I am wanting to achieve?  I am after the best performing solution.

If there are any questions please dont hesitate in letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to improve performance then I would consider a couple of things:

1- Stop downloading the XML into a file on disk and then reloading the file into XML.  Using HttpWebRequest or HttpClient you can retrieve the data as a stream and then load that stream directly into an XElement/XDocument object.

2- Instead of loading into a DataTable I would use Linq2Xml to query over the document and create a collection of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and I have modified my code to use Linq2Xml, still a bit slow (nothing is ever as fast as you want it), but for now this is OK.  When I put it into production I will need to look at any performance issues that are still around.

Comment: @Lima What I have done is use the primary representation to fill comboboxes with a single entry.  Then when the user clicks the down arrow, I make the request to populate the complete list.  This avoids having to make multiple requests to fill lists when launching a screen.

Answer (score -1):

In the past, I've successfully used [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse the result from calls to Google Translation API or the Twitter API.

Comment: He specifically is asking how to parse XML and you provide him with a Json parser!

Comment: Ah, OK. I read _"Can anyone advise if there is a better method doing what I am wanting to achieve?"_ and thought he was flexible in how to achieve the element. So I was wrong, sorry for that. Thanks for clarifying, Darrel.